# Caveats to be aware of when using threading in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm quite new to threading in Python and have a couple of beginner questions.

When starting more than say fifty threads using the Python `threading` module I start getting `MemoryError`. The threads themselves are very slim and not very memory hungry, so it seems like it is the overhead of the threading that causes the memory issues.

- Is there something I can do to increase the memory capacity or otherwise make Python allow for a larger number of threads?
- What is the maximum number of threads you've been able to run in your Python code using the `threading` module? Did you do any tricks to achieve that number?
- Are there any other caveats to be aware of when using the `threading` module?

Comment: How much memory does your computer have?

Comment: Usually you want *as few threads as you need*. Sounds like you think you want *as many as you can*.

Comment: THC4k: Where in the question do you get that impression? The number of threads needed is obviously a function of the problem domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eventlets](http://eventlet.net/doc/)-Threads have been designed for low memory consumption.
The general purpose call [spawn](http://eventlet.net/doc/basic_usage.html#greenthread-spawn) can be easily used to spawn new threads.

Comment: Also take a look at gevent, which was built to fix some of the Eventlet's bugs and has much better performance.

Answer (score 5):

Your question cannot be answered in a general way, as good usage of threading always depends on concrete problem to be solved. You also do not tell us, which Python version you are using, so I assume you use the "default" CPython and not IronPython or something like that. To give you some hints and ideas to further think about your problem:

- Why do you need so much treads? Your machine will probably not be able to run them in parallel anyway.
- Have a look at Stackless Python. Don't know the current status of the project, but I think it was designed for that kind of problems.
- The global interpreter lock prevents pure Python code from really running in parallel. But C methods can be run in parallel, so in real life it's sometimes hard to guess, how Python will behave regarding parallelization.
- Python has many good libraries. Have a look whether one of them already has a solution for your design problem. If your problem is network related, have a look at Twisted for example.

Answer (score 2):

The [Global Interpreter Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil) is known to have a strong impact on the performance limitations of standard CPython. Thus the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) notes:

> multiprocessing is a package that
>   supports spawning processes using an
>   API similar to the threading module.
>   The multiprocessing package offers
>   both local and remote concurrency,
>   effectively side-stepping the Global
>   Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses
>   instead of threads. Due to this, the
>   multiprocessing module allows the
>   programmer to fully leverage multiple
>   processors on a given machine. It runs
>   on both Unix and Windows.

The GIL probably isn't the cause of your MemoryErrors, but it is something to be aware of.